# Windows 10 Photos App "Clarity" option algorithm

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-10

I want to add an option in my C# app to adjust photo clarity. I searched through the web a lot, and found many implementations for effects like sharpening and blur, but didn't find any C# (or at least C++) implementation for image clarity.

I'm looking for something like clarity adjustment in the Windows 10 Photos app. If you open the editor section, under "Adjust" tab you will find the clarity option.
[Here is an screenshot from Windows 10 Photos App Clarity Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChkBM.png)

I don't know how this option works! Is it just a sharpening effect, or is it mixed with some other image processing effects?

I would appreciate it if you would give me an implementation or a library that does this effect.

Here is three screenshots:
[Clarity slider at zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jsB1.png)
[Clarity slider at minimum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAAgn.png)
[Clarity slider at maximum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0cAs.png)

Thanks